# User Interaction Enabled in Identity Inspector, Attributes Inspector?

Tags: interface-builder, xcode4

What is the difference between "User Interaction Enabled" in the Identity Inspector as opposed to the "User Interaction Enabled" in the attributes inspector? They are not linked and only the latter seems to have any effect.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Xcode: Why does "User Interaction Enabled" appear twice?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5603867/xcode-why-does-user-interaction-enabled-appear-twice)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the explanation given here:
[Xcode: Why does "User Interaction Enabled" appear twice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5603867/xcode-why-does-user-interaction-enabled-appear-twice)

Comment: That's cool. I'm going to upvote you but mark the question as a dupe :)

Comment: when you get enough points (not sure how many) you'll see a "close" link under the question. This question did not get enough votes to get closed, so it was kept open. So congrats or something...