# Custom UIView in UITableViewCell

Tags: uiview, uitableview

One of the UITableViewCells in my table contains a UIView which is like a 5-star ratings. However, the view cannot be selected.

The tutorial I'm basing it on is the following from Ray Wenderlich:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/1768/how-to-make-a-custom-uiview-a-5-star-rating-view

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is `User Interaction Enabled` checked for the rating view in your storyboard file? In the Utilities right-hand sidebar of the storyboard editor, under the "Attributes" inspector's "View" section, you should find the "User Interaction Enabled" checkbox. (A similar checkbox also appears in the "Identity" inspector, [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5603867/xcode-why-does-user-interaction-enabled-appear-twice) for details.)